# Unit testing class that inherits from Dictionary base class

Tags: c#, enums, nunit

I have the following code:

```
public class DiagnosticsSettings : Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        public string GetStringValue(string settingName)
        {
            return TryGetValue(settingName, out var result) ? result : throw new UnknownDiagnosticSettingException($"Unable to locate setting with name {settingName}.");
        }


 public T GetEnumValue<T>(string settingName)
        {
            var stringValue = GetStringValue(settingName);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue))
                throw new UnknownDiagnosticSettingException($"Unable to locate setting with name { settingName }");

            return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), stringValue);
        }
```

I'm trying to unit test and have tried as follows:

```
     [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            var settings = new DiagnosticsSettings();
            var value = settings.GetEnumValue<CreatedOn>(CreatedOn.Today.ToString());
            Assert.AreEqual(1, value);
        }
```

My Enum class looks like this:

```
 public enum CreatedOn
    {
        Today = 1,
        All = 2
    }
```

However I keep getting the error: "Unable to locate setting with name Today".

Do I need to pass in settings to the unit test to get this to pass?

Any guidance would be really appreciated, thanks

Comment: Well you're not adding anything to the `Dictionary` so any call to `TryGetValue` is going to fail.

Comment: Thanks @DavidG - how can I do this?

Comment: Well, add it to the dictionary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't adding any `KeyVlauePair`s into the dictionary, so `GetStringValue` will always be null.

See this example, which should work:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var settings = new DiagnosticsSettings { ["Today"] = "SomeValue" };
    var value = settings.GetEnumValue<CreatedOn>(CreatedOn.Today.ToString());
    Assert.AreEqual(1, value);
}
```

On another note, inheriting from a class such as `Dictionary` is rarely good practice. It provides a lot of behaviour, most of which you probably don't want to be exposing to consumers.

A better approach may be to use composition:

```
public class DiagnosticsSettings
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> _dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public string GetStringValue(string settingName)
    {
        return _dict.TryGetValue(settingName, out var result) ? result : throw new UnknownDiagnosticSettingException($"Unable to locate setting with name {settingName}.");
    }


    public T GetEnumValue<T>(string settingName)
    {
        var stringValue = GetStringValue(settingName);

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue))
            throw new UnknownDiagnosticSettingException($"Unable to locate setting with name { settingName }");

        return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), stringValue);
    }
}
```

Which would only expose the desired behaviour.

If you want to retain the dictionary initialiser, you will also need to implement `IEnumerable` and `Add(string, string)`:

```
public class DiagnosticsSettings : IEnumerable
{
    // ...

    public void Add(string arg1, string arg2)
    {
        _dict.Add(arg1, arg2);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _dict.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```